# UiPath- Regex to replace the value only of Title

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to write a regex that replaces the value of title "Downloading" with "installing"

Here's How the input looks like

```
Title="[Installing %=System.LinkedTitle.Installing%]" Value="Installing"
Title="Introduction"
Title="Storing equipment &amp; lubrication"
Title="Installing the collector laterals" 
Title="Installing the mechanical scraper" 
Title="Installing the saturator system"
Title="Installing the sludge beach" 
Title="Installing the effluent weir"
Title="[Installing%=System.LinkedTitle%]"
```

And the output should look like:

```
Title="[Installing %=System.LinkedTitle.Installing%]" Value="Installing"
Title="Introduction"
Title="Storing equipment &amp; lubrication"
Title="Downloading the collector laterals" 
Title="Downloading the mechanical scraper" 
Title="Downloading the saturator system"
Title="Downloading the sludge beach" 
Title="Downloading the effluent weir"
Title="[Installing%=System.LinkedTitle%]"
```

`(?<!\[)Installing(?![^[\]]*%])`

This regex highlights installing both for title and value, I just want the title value to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to replace installing with Downloading.

You can exclude `Value=` using another negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\[)(?<!\bValue=")Installing(?![^[\]]*%])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5hV3G/1)

Or if supported, using an alternation in the lookbehind:

```
(?<!\[|\bValue=")Installing(?![^[\]]*%])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Szdiyj/1)

But if you just want `Installing` right after `Title="` then

```
(?<=\bTitle=")Installing\b
```

Comment: what if i want all the Installing to get selected in title   Title="Installing the mechanical Installing scraperInstalling" value="Installing"

Comment: @HansenClydeLobo You are using UiPath, which I think uses the .NET regex engine. In that case there are multiple ways to accomplish that. For example `(?<=\bTitle=""[^""]*)\bInstalling\b(?=[^[\]]*"")` https://regex101.com/r/mcAiFA/1 or `(?<=\bTitle=""[^""]*)\bInstalling\b(?![^[\]]*%])` https://regex101.com/r/mZ96cu/1 or more specific https://regex101.com/r/aaWN9K/1 I am not sure if you have the escape the `\"` or use double `""` to match a single quotes in UiPath.